# What is "-inkey privateKey.key" in openssl command

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am trying to convert a PEM, P7B & CRT to PFX using OpenSSL using the following commands:

```
OpenSSL pkcs7 -print_certs -in certificate.p7b -out certificate.cer

openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.cer -inkey privateKey.key -out certificate.pfx -certfile CACert.cer
```

My question is what is "-inkey privateKey.key" in the second command, I did not receive a .key file from Godaddy.

Comment: When you obtain a certificate from a proper CA like GoDaddy the sequence is (1) **generate** keypair (private AND public -- for openssl these are _both_ in the 'privatekey' file, which can be confusing) (2) generate CSR containing public key (openssl can combine #1 and #2 using `req -newkey -keyout`) (3) provide CSR to CA, plus other evidence and payment as needed (4) CA provides EE cert, plus any needed chain cert(s) (5) use cert(s) from #4 WITH **privatekey from #1**, which can include combining them into PKCS12/PFX.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-pkcs12.html#PKCS-12-output-export-options), this is how you insert a private key into the keystore/p12 file.

You run the openssl command to generate a .csr and .key file, then you submit the .csr file to the certificate authority and they send you back a signed certificate with a public key (.pem or .crt).  You then have a .key file (private) and a .pem file (public).